# Ubunu 20.04 How do I make python code executeable by double-click and show output in a new window?

Tags: python, filemanager

I'm trying to make a python script I made execute on a double-click in the file manager. I want it to show the output in a new window. So far, all It's doing when I double-click is opening the file in a text editor.

I've tried adding a bunch of different shebangs to the beginning of the file, but none of them have gotten me anywhere. Here is an image of my terminal, I've tried all the different paths listed in the whereis commands.

[Attempted Shebang List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ma8Tm.png)

When I do get this file to execute on double-click, will it automatically show the output in a different window, or will I need to add something in the code specifically telling it to do that?

Comment: One way: Look up how to use [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) to open a window for your output.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously that doesn't really work out of the box - I've tried and failed:

1. Set `#!/usr/bin/env python` as first line in your script
2. use `chmod +x` to make it executable

When I clicked on the file in the file manager, it still asked me what to to with it. So I went to the

```
~/.local/share/applications/
```

folder and created a desktop file, e.g. "MyProg.desktop" (the ending .desktop is mandatory)
It contains those lines:

`[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Merge
Exec=/home/user/your/path/to/file.py %f
Categories=Other;
MimeType=text/x-qml
Terminal=false`

Note: the %f will give you the change to pass a file to your python script, which gets the data in the sys.argv argument. 
The "MimeType" is just an example and may be omitted

Now you have a full fledged "Program", you could use. It behaves like any other program, you've installed.